# Find solution of this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve this ODE
$$
y^2\left(1+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right)=C
$$
where $C$ is positive constant.

Then I have $y=\pm\sqrt{C}$.
Is it right $y=\pm\sqrt{C}$ is only the solution to that ODE?

Comment: $(x-C_0)^2+y^2=C$ where $C_0\in \mathbb{R}$ is also a solution. (Here you're obviously assuming that $C>0.)$

Comment: Yes, I assume that $C>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^2\left(1+\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2\right)=C$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \pm \sqrt {\frac{C}{y^2} - 1} \,$ (for $|y| \lt C$)

$\dfrac{ydy}{\sqrt{C-y^2}} = \pm dx$

$x = C' \pm {\sqrt{C-y^2}} \implies (x - C')^2 + y^2 = C$